# what is the unicode for € symbol

Tags: java, unicode, unicode-string, javaquery

I am trying to output the Unicode for € to the screen. I can't find / don't know the symbol for it.

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20aC/index.htm

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro_sign

Comment: Here: [Displaying euro symbol using unicode and changing characters to uppercase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174270/displaying-euro-symbol-using-unicode-and-changing-characters-to-uppercase)

Answer (score 5):

```
 System.out.println("\u20ac");
```

This prints out the Euro symbol.

Comment: ... Provided that the output device has even a glyph to represent the code point!

Answer (score 0):

Unicode number: `U+20AC`
HTML code: `&#8364;`