# Why euro symbol printing as Ôé¼?

Tags: java, printing, epson

I have an Epson tm-t20 configured with codepage 858. I did a test print of the codepage and the characters are fine. The Java class is UTF-8 encoded. I'm trying to print some text with characters like **é**, **ç** and **€** present in the already named codepage.

The printer is compatible with these Docflavors:

```
Arrays.stream(service.getSupportedDocFlavors()).forEach(f->System.out.println(f.getMediaType()+":"+f.getMimeType()+":"+f.getRepresentationClassName()));

image:image/gif:[B
image:image/gif:java.io.InputStream
image:image/gif:java.net.URL
image:image/jpeg:[B
image:image/jpeg:java.io.InputStream
image:image/jpeg:java.net.URL
image:image/png:[B
image:image/png:java.io.InputStream
image:image/png:java.net.URL
application:application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref:java.awt.print.Pageable
application:application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref:java.awt.print.Printable
application:application/octet-stream:[B
application:application/octet-stream:java.net.URL
application:application/octet-stream:java.io.InputStream
```

So far I tried:

**Attemp 1:** with InputStream

```
public static void print(){
  InputStream bytes = new ByteArrayInputStream(("Estó ès una pruebà \r\n Hola qu€ tal").getBytes());    
  PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
  DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
  DocPrintJob pj = service.createPrintJob();
  Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(bytes, flavor, null);
  pj.print(doc, null);
}
```

Output:

```
Est├│ ├¿s una prueb├á
Hola quÔé¼ tal
```

**Attept 2:** with byte[], same output

```
 public static void print(){
    byte[] bytes = new String("Estó ès una pruebà \r\n Hola qu€ tal").getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
    DocPrintJob pj = service.createPrintJob();
    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(bytes, flavor, null);
    pj.print(doc, null);
}
```

Any idea what can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use attempt 2, with one change: when using `Charset.forName`, you should not pass UTF-8 as the charset, but rather `"Cp858"` (given by the [supported encodings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) documentation for Java). The encoding should be based on the codepage the printer expects, and the fact that the Java source is UTF-8 is not relevant to this conversion.

Answer (score 2):

That's enconding issue. You will have to use unicode if you want to print euro symbol and anothers symbols.

Example of printing euro symbol with unicode

```
System.out.println("\u20ac");
```

However, check this question [Displaying euro symbol using unicode and changing characters to uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174270/displaying-euro-symbol-using-unicode-and-changing-characters-to-uppercase) and take a look of andrewdotn's answer, it's really well explained.

Answer (score 0):

It is encoding issue.Platform's default charset must be treating euro symbol as garbage character.
You need to pass charset with these read and write operations as precautions.
Read this article:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-io-inputstreamreader-class/